# CSS Background Image & drop shadow

Tags: css

I'm struggling with getting a background image on this page and a drop shadow to show on top of my tab.... [URL_REMOVED]

The left tab should be "below" the white content area, thus the shadow effect should be on top of the tab.  The second issue is that I'm using CSS to apply a gradient background, I also want to have a background image as well and it's not working.  Can anyone help me figure out why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add postion:relative to #main and #side. z-index works only on positioned(absolute/relative) elements.

```
#main {
    …
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

#side {
    …    
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Sweet - good call on that... any ideas about the background image?

Comment: Have you tried to define your gradient colors in rgba()? rgba(0,0,0,0.5) is 50% black.